# How ex file is going to compile

Tags: elixir

When I have an elixir file and will compile it, what does the compiler do first? Compile ex to erlang or directly to bytecode?
When I write following code into session interaction

```
iex(4)> double = fn x -> x * 2 end
#Function<6.54118792/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
```

What does compiler do? Compile it to erlang or directly to bytecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles the code to an Erlang [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is then compiled to bytecode by the [compile module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html) from OTP. The relevant source code is in [elixir_compiler.erl](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_compiler.erl):

```
compile:noenv_forms([no_auto_import()|Forms], [return, {source, Source}|ErlOpts])
```